# Hide controller name when calling its methods

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm creating a website using CakePHP.
It has user Registration and Login system.

So at first i have a `controller` called `HomeController` which has three methods

1) `index();`

2) `login();`

3) `register();`

by default `index()` method will execute.

i have the following code to call other two methods.

```
<? php

echo $this->Html->link('Login',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'login'),array('escape'=>FALSE));

echo $this->Html->link('Register',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'register'),array('escape'=>FALSE));

?>
```

So now when i click on the above links (`login`,`register`) it will call appropriate method and the `url` will be something like

`www.example.com/home/login` and `www.example.com/home/register`

Now **i want to remove the controller name from the url** since the method is in the same controller.

So the `url` should look like

`www.example.com/login` and `www.example.com/register`

is it possible??
Please help..

Comment: use routing http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2009/11/02/cakephp-s-routing-explained

Comment: i ll take a look.. thanq..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in app\Config\routes.php add following lines

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'register'));
```

It will convert default urls to your desired urls

```
www.example.com/login and www.example.com/register
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Router::parseExtensions('json'); 
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'home', 
                                'action' => 'login'));

Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'home', 
                                    'action' => 'login'));
```

Comment: maybe you could elaborate on your answer a little, explaining how it solves the problem - this will help others in the future